# how to pass javascript function values to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my javascript function, I want to pass all my cart-Items in a textbox so that I can easily found all my cart items

```
function initListaOrcamento() {
    var products = $.CestaFeira({
        debug: true
      }).getItems(),
      totalValueTemp = 0,
      $cartItems = $('#cart-items');
```

Comment: Can I explain a bit more, it's not really clear what your problem is

Comment: in above code all my cart items are stored in $cartItems so i want these items to be displayed into some text box.Do you have any other method to display all these items to some display area?

Answer (score 0):

to pass objects into a textbox, you can use this code:

```
$(‘#id').html(yourcartitems)
```

Comment: Thansk for reply but plz tell me here whats the id means  and where this piece of code is inserted ,into a function or somewhere else?